# How do I get a dynamic href tag with JSP with a value from java class

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I'm able to get the href tag dynamic now, but now unable to acccess the HashMap from my MMTUtil which gives mw the value corresponding to my Key(objectName)gUnable to think of any solution I have imported the class in the JSP thats how far I'm able to go

```
MMTUtil.getDomainComboDocumentationMap().get(objectName);
```

where objectName is a key and I need to get the value out of it So that it can be used in href

What I have tried:
I think this might not work

```
<%
UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO = new UMRDocumentationDTO();
String objectName = documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName();  //getting error here and the debgger goes directly at the end of the page
String tc = MMTUtil.getDomainComboDocumentationMap().get(objectName);
%>
```

can we try something like this?

```
for (Map.Entry entry : MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().entrySet()){
        Object documentationLink =  entry.getValue();
}



<td><a href="<%=documentationLink%>" target="_blank"
id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property
value="domainName" /></a>
```

I'm unable to access the Value from my Map in Jsp any error?

```
public class MMTUtil
{

private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap             = null;

static
{
    domainDocumentationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    domainComboDocumentationMap =new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap() {
    return domainDocumentationMap;
}

public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(String objectName, String documentationLink) {
    MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap.put(objectName, documentationLink);

//        for(Map.Entry entry:MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap.entrySet()){
//            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
//        }
    }
```

Comment: use javascript (or jquery) - ask a webservice / servlet (ajax) for the value and then use jquery to fill it in

Answer (score 2):

You need to use expression tag `href="<%=tc%>"`

If you are getting the correct path in tc.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: @user7474502 You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)